# Typescript React: How to open a static HTML page onClick event

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, svg, button

I want to open a new window that is a static HTML page within my Typescript/React project. The new window should appear after an onClick event, I am using an SVG for the "button" I want it to go inside of the href within the  tag, I put a placeholder within the href link for readability

```
<a id="www-icon" href="staticpage.html">
  <svg></svg>
</a>
```

My html file is within my public folder since I found a few answers that mentioned it should go there, yet when I click on the button I remain on the same page as my project (when viewing through live server) The only thing that changes is my url address http://localhost:3000/staticpage.html

What do I need to change/add for this page to open in a new window?